# How to append values to array of type [[String:String]] in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm working with this kind of array.

```
var myArray : [[String:String]] = [["1" : "Arun", "2" : "Gupta"],["1" : "John", "2" : "Cena"],["1" : "James" , "2" : "Bond"],["1" : "Iron", "2" : "Man"],["1" : "Karthik","2" : "Keyan"]]
```

I could assign values directly to this array and access the values through object. For example,

To access values in index zero.

```
let obj = myArray[0]
print(obj["1"],obj["2"])
```

it prints values in `myArray[0]`

Output:

```
Arun Gupta.
```

Now what i want is, how to append values to this kind of array instead of directly assigning values in the declaration itself.

Comment: you mean `myArray.append(["1" : "Arun", "2" : "Gupta"])`

Comment: yes, and how this array must be declared ? 'var myArray : [[String:String]] ' is this right ?

Comment: you can just declare like `var myArray = [[String:String]]()`

Comment: It works only after including this '()' parentheses. Thanks!. i wonder why this kind of array requires this parentheses ?

Comment: @KarthikeyanSk, because it's call of initialiser (`Array<[String:String]>.init()`), all function calls require parentheses.

Comment: @KarthikeyanSk You can also use `var myArray: [[String: String]] = []` to initialize your array.

Comment: Oh i see!. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `append()`

```
var myArray = [[String:String]]()
myArray.append(["1" : "Arun", "2" : "Gupta"])
print(myArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
var array1 = ["1" : "Arun", "2" : "Gupta"]

myArray.append(array1)
```

Comment: Should the declaration be like this ' var myArray : [[String:String]] '